# Probability of getting at least 3 heads when flipping four coins

Tags: probability

Is there a way to solve the problem considering that the probability of getting a head is 1/2 and then calculating $.5^4$ and multiplying $.5^4$ by 4 as there are 4 ways that this could occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is precisely how you do it, but you must also add the probability of getting 4 heads.

Comment: my book says the answer is 5/16.  $$4nCr 3 + 4 ncR 4 / (2^4)$$                               $2^4$ comes from that fact that there are $2^4$ outcomes in the sample space. How is my solution wrong?

Comment: @Ben You need to add the probability of all 4 coins showing up as heads.

This is because at least 3 heads encompasses the events where you have 3 heads and 1 tail, or 4 heads.

Comment: In this case the number of possible events is so small that you can write a list of all possible sequences of coin tosses with three or more heads (there are only five such sequences), and see for yourself how the numbers add up.

Answer (score 3):

The probability of at least three heads can be found by
$$
\sum_{k = 3}^4\binom{4}{k}.5^k.5^{4-k} = \frac{5}{16}
$$
The reason being is we have four coins and we want to choose 3 or more heads.  Therefore, we sum the the binomial distribution for 4 choose 3 and 4 choose 4 with probability of a fair coin so $p = q = 0.5$.

The binomial distribution is
$$
\binom{n}{k}p^kq^{n -k}
$$
where $q = 1 - p$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 5/16 because in total there are 16 possibilities when tossing a coin 4 times. I.e. $2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2 = 2^4$.

And the possibilities of getting atleast three head is 5 that is we can get HHHT, HHTH, HTHH, THHH, and HHHH

Thus, the answer is 5/16.